# How to concatenate two MP4 files, which require http basic Authorization: Bearer <base64,user:password>, using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, concatenation

Hello dear ffmpeg experts!

I ran the following command, which worked perfectly:

ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist https,concat,tls,tcp -i "concat:[https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_0.m4v|https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_1.m4v|https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_2.m4v"](https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_0.m4v%7Chttps://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_1.m4v%7Chttps://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k_2.m4v%22) -c:v copy -vframes 180 -y Movie_of_6_seconds.mp4

I followed the recommended solution of the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641562/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-which-require-http-basic-authorization-bearer

You can execute the command on your local computer and see that it should run just fine...

I used 3. concat protocol, which does indeed concat init + progressive segments

However... when every segment on a server I refer to, is password protected, it fails with 401 Unauthorized, even though I added the following line: -headers "Authorization: Bearer bas64user:password" , before specifying the -i "concat:...".

It seems to me... that the headers don't pass to the concat command inside of the input of ffmpeg... and it simply ignores them. When I used the same -headers command, on a single file, without concat, it passed the authorization successfully

Notes:

- Even though every segment has a length of 120 frames (So in maximum, I could have generated 2*120 = 240 frames... I wanted a movie of 6 seconds and not 8... And by this way, to test that ffmpeg is smart enough to stop processing the whole input). To do that, I used -vframes 180, where 180 / 30 (FPS) = 6 seconds
- I used -c:v copy, to get without re-encoding, only the video part (No audio!)
- I used -y to override existing file...
- 0.m4v, is the init file! it is a small file, that has metadata of the original video which was produced with mpeg-dash
- 1.m4v and 2.m4v, are the progressive segments

Is there a way, to pass the http basic headers (Authorization: Bearer) to all of the chained files?

Like:

- Via a json content type on the ffmpeg request
- Or user:password@video_segment (Although... it seems to me it's not a header?)
- Somehow specify header inside the concat command?
  I don't want to first download all files and then get rid of the password protected... as it both takes ridiculous time & other resources... and I would like to record from a segment that is "endless", meaning a camera that keeps streaming data.

Thanks in advance ,

FFmpeg noobie